# IntelliJ IDEA global search

Tags: search, full-text-search, intellij-idea

I would like to search across projects for variable usages, or at least for strings.  I've got [IndexYourFiles](http://www.indexyourfiles.com/) which works well for text searches, but I have to re-index every now and then and would like an integrated solution.

Is there any way that I can search across projects in IntelliJ IDEA? So far I have only been able to search within the currently-open project.  I'm guessing IntelliJ can't do this natively; are there any plug-ins out there to support this?

Thanks.

Comment: IntelliJ is project-oriented, in the contrary to Eclipse, where you can open as many projects as you want. The IntelliJ way is to have multiple IDE windows. Hence I don't know any way to search across all IntelliJ projects (all opened now? or anytime? or in recent list?)

Comment: Like Rachel mentioned, I've only been able to search the currently-opened project by doing Ctrl+Shift+F.

Comment: In some buggy cases you must go "File > invalidate caches" and restart.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

IntelliJ is project based so you can only search within the open project using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>(Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>(Mac).

When I need to search across a set of projects I use [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home)

Comment: "you can only search within the open project" -->That's not right as of today. You are also able to search through you a folder using Ctrl + Shift + F.

Comment: It might also be ctrl + shift + F on a mac ( tested on version 2017.3 )

Answer (score 12):

IntelliJ 13 (at least) has "Edit/Find/Find in Path...".
It has the Scope option which can be set to a directory, so if all projects are in the same directory (e.g. IdeaProjects) then it will search all projects.

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep`.

In the terminal, go to the root directory of your project, and type `grep -r my_string_here .`.

You can add color to your search with `--color` (just add `alias grep='grep --color' to your`.bash_profile`, and add`-i` to make your search case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

In the IntelliJ now it is very easy to find the anything through just two clicks and search on the bar.

Double click on `shift` and enter the keyword in the search bar.
I'm using ubuntu which I found the shortcut.

Comment: Double Shift doesn't search plain text; you need Ctrl+Shift+F like the accepted answer says: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000018990-Why-doesn-t-Search-Everywhere-work-?page=1#community_comment_115000032724

Answer (score 1):

My workplace eventually set up [Atlassian Fisheye](https://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) which allows us to search for code or specific files across all of our projects, and it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac its double shift (search files, classes, all ...), type /url + and place your endpoint. You will only see a list of endpoints matching to similar pattern.

[image: Search files in intellij]