# Finding a words in all files of a project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

How can I find a word in all file in IntelliJ IDEA project?
In EclipseIDE, `Ctrl+H` and search file.
Is there any shortcut?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA global search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937184/intellij-idea-global-search)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On my Mac, it's cmd+shift+f.

You can see which shortcut it is in your machine by navigating to Edit/Find/Find in Path

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I know how to find the other shortcuts.

Answer (score 6):

Select your project and:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> should do.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the main menu, choose `Edit | Find | Find in Path`, or press `Ctrl+Shift+F`

It's all described in the **[IntelliJ IDEA Help section](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#d1638921e123)**.

[image]